# Ignore specific special character in indexing Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch for my usecase and using below analyser-

```
            "edgengram_": {
              "filter" : ["lowercase"],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "edgengram_tokenizer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer" : {
            "edgengram_tokenizer" : {
              "min_gram" : "1",
              "type" : "edge_ngram",
              "max_gram" : "24",
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "punctuation",
                "symbol"
                ]
            }
          }
```

Please, someone, help me with the below case.
For text "(m&a)"
Tokens are - [(, (m, (m&, (m&a]

But I need tokens as [m, m&, m&a]

So here I want to consider all special characters apart from parenthesis [(, )].
What changes do I need to make in my analyzer settings? Please someone help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mapping Character Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html)

> The mapping character filter accepts a map of keys and values. Whenever it encounters a string of characters that is the same as a key, it replaces them with the value associated with that key.

**Settings**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "( => ",
            ") => "
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 24,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
POST index168/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "(m&a)"
}
```

**Tokens**

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "m",
      "start_offset" : 1,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "m&",
      "start_offset" : 1,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "m&a",
      "start_offset" : 1,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can we replace parenthesis with space?

Comment: @Sanchit you can use notation \\u0020 for space